# array item match and separate all item

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$info`.I wan to make two array from this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7
            [type] => general
            [description] => <p>One</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8
            [type] => general
            [description] => <p>Two</p>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [type] => rules
            [description] => <p>One</p>
        )

)
```

I wan to make two array from this array.

if any array item type will be rules then these array item goes to one array and if any item type will be general then these array item goes to another array

I use this but not work

```
    function myfunction($products, $needle)
    {
       foreach($products as $key => $product)
       {
          if ( $product['type'] === $needle )

                $a=array( );
                return $a=$product[];






       }

        return false;

    }
```

My Output array is this.there i call my function two time.

```
$output = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
                'rules'=>myfunction($info,'rules'),
                'general'=>myfunction($info,'general')

        );
```

I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your function stops after the first item which matches your type (see the `return`?). Secondly, you are missing curly braces after your if (the array will only be initialized if the type matches, but the return will be executed every time). Also `return $a = $product[];` doesn't make much sense, I wonder that it even compiles. The following function should work as expected

```
function myfunction($products, $needle)
{
   $a = array();
   foreach($products as $key => $product)
   {
      if ( $product['type'] === $needle ) {
        $a[] = $product;
       }
   }

   return $a;
}
```

*But* you don't need to roll your own function, PHP already has an `array_filter` function:

```
$rules = array_filter($info, function($item) { return $item['type'] === 'rules'; });
$general = array_filter($info, function($item) { return $item['type'] === 'general'; });
```